# Angular2+ - Get number from a json that contains only a number value

Tags: json, angular, numbers

My json file only contains a single int value, I know to get values from json arrays. But having trouble when the file only contains one value

JSON File:

```
12
```

Service.ts method:

```
getNumberWithObservable(): Observable<number> {
    return this.http.get("myurl").map((res: Response) => res.json());
}
```

This returns a observable array contains

How do I get the number value from the observable array in angular 2 or higher.

Component.ts - getter method

```
//returns a object but need the number
console.log(this.myService.getNumberWithObservable());
```

I have tried `this.myService.getNumberWithObservable().get(0)` but gives error

Comment: have you tried `this.myService.getNumberWithObservable()[0]`?

Comment: Im getting a red line under 'get' saying "[ts] Property 'get' does not exsist on type string"

Comment: have you tried the usual way of getting a json array value?

Comment: I usually get  my array values on html file, and view them on a table or something.  ex .`*ngFor="let candy of candies  | async"`I haven't gotten array element and assigned them to a value yet. In this calse i'm trying to get the number value and assign it

Comment: if i were you, remove the `: Observable<number>` and try `this.myService.getNumberWithObservable()[0]`

Comment: now im getting `[ts] Property 'get' does not exist on type Observable<any>`

Comment: what if you try `console.log(this.myService.getNumberWithObservable())` now?

Comment: It worked now. with `getNumberWithObservable()[0]`  output is `undefined` and with `this.myService.getNumberWithObservable()`output is `[object Object]` I tried change the observable to `Observable<number>`is still giving me `undefined`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159895/discussion-between-mast3rd3mon-and-java-gamer).